Position Flex parent to always be at the bottom of the page
I'm trying to set my 'div--stats' flex container to always be at the bottom of the page, currently I can only do this by manually setting the margin-top to be 430px, however I want to be able to do this automatically.


*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  /*
    2. Remove default margin
  */
  * {
    margin: 0;
  }
  /*
    Typographic tweaks!
    3. Add accessible line-height
    4. Improve text rendering
  */
  body {
    line-height: 1.5;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    height: 100%;
  }
  /*
    5. Improve media defaults
  */
  img, picture, video, canvas, svg {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  /*
    6. Remove built-in form typography styles
  */
  input, button, textarea, select {
    font: inherit;
  }
  /*
    7. Avoid text overflows
  */
  p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
  }
  /*
    8. Create a root stacking context
  */
  #root, #__next {
    isolation: isolate;
  }

  .main--container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

.b--color {
    background-color: red
}

.button--container {
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 150px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start
}

.button--header {
  flex-grow: 0;
  font-family: "Jersey 15", Courier, monospace;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.button--element {
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: "Jersey 15", Courier, monospace;
    align-self: center;
    height: 40px;
    flex-basis: 200px;
    transition: all 0.15s linear;
}

.button--element:hover {
  border-color: 2px solid black;
  cursor:grab;
}
.previous--colorsh1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Jersey 15", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 54px;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    color: white;
}

.div--stats {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-top: 5px solid white;
  background-color: black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-top: 410px;
}

.color--history {
  color: white;
}


.color--history li {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: "Jersey 15", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jersey+15&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="main--container">
  <div class="button--container">
      <button class="button--element">Press to change color</button>
      <h1 class="button--header">Color</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="div--stats">
      <h1 class="previous--colorsh1">Previous Colors</h1>
      <ul class="color--history">
          <li>Test</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>



I've attempted to follow some posts regarding this, but I've attempted to set the first flex parent container to justify-content: space-between however this doesn't seem to work. Setting margin-top: auto will place the div container underneath the button div. As said, setting it to 430px seems to work, if this is the best way of doing it I'm happy to leave it as, and set to flex grow as the list will be populated as it's going to hold different list items.
Feel like I've over complicated the styling of the other divs.

It is not very clear what you want to achieve. If you want the div--stats div to be below button--container you can add flex-direction:column; to .main--container. But if you want it to just be always at the bottom you can use fixed postion with bottom: 0

Would this be what you are looking for?
https://jsfiddle.net/rLnj576d/10/
/*
1. Use a more-intuitive box-sizing model.
*/
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*
    2. Remove default margin
  */
* {
  margin: 0;
}

/*
    Typographic tweaks!
    3. Add accessible line-height
    4. Improve text rendering
  */
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display:flex;
}

/*
    5. Improve media defaults
  */
img,
picture,
video,
canvas,
svg {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/*
    6. Remove built-in form typography styles
  */
input,
button,
textarea,
select {
  font: inherit;
}

/*
    7. Avoid text overflows
  */
p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

/*
    8. Create a root stacking context
  */
#root,
#__next {
  isolation: isolate;
}

.main--container {
  flex-grow:1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.b--color {
  background-color: red
}

.button--container {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-grow:1;
}

.button--header {
  flex-grow: 0;
  font-family: "Jersey 15", Courier, monospace;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.button--element {
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: "Jersey 15", Courier, monospace;
  align-self: center;
  height: 40px;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  transition: all 0.15s linear;
}

.button--element:hover {
  border-color: 2px solid black;
  cursor: grab;
}

.previous--colorsh1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Jersey 15", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 54px;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.div--stats {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-top: 5px solid white;
  background-color: black;
  flex:1 1 0;
  /* margin-top: 410px; */
}

.color--history {
  color: white;
}


.color--history li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: "Jersey 15", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}




many thanks for your reply, that has done the trick! I've used a compare code tool and just running through what you've done. If i'm reading it correctly, the main div (that holds the two div children) has been set to grow and column based (assume that pushed the column that you've correctly made stay pushed to the bottom of the page). Thank you once again.

You pretty much nailed it.  Main div is flex-parent of column containing two siblings.  Button container, top component, with flex grow of 1 takes up all available space, and div--states with a flex grow of 0 flex shrink of 1 and basis of 0 only takes up as much space as it needs. so gets pushed down by the button container.

This can be done easily with flexbox and margin auto.
But first you need to make sure that everything it's set for it to work properly.
The parents must fill the viewport as you expect in order to put it in the bottom.
Here you have a simple example of putting an element at the bottom with flexbox.


*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Make sure <html> and <body> fill the viewport */
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Avoid flex-items to shrink by default */
* {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

:root {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
}

.main-container {
  /* make sure .main-container fills its parent */
  height: 100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  overflow: auto;
  
  & > .bottom {
    margin-top: auto;
  }
}


.top {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #06f;
}

.bottom {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #90f;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main-container">
            <div class="top"></div>
            <div class="bottom"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>



